# Are MTG card identification questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I have a foreign card that I just cannot identify. I figured the community would be able to help me identify it, but I wanted to make sure this sort of question is allowed on this site.

Comment: I think the arguments for and against this sort of thing are covered pretty well [here](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/196/6692).

Answer (score 6):

I think it should be allowed. As long as you provide a picture, the question is clearly answerable. I'd suggest that you just ask the question. In the worst case, your question is closed an you lose a few rep.

As an aside, this mirrors Arqade's game identification policy. They allow it, but only if you provide a picture, video, or sound clip.

Answer (score 4):

This question is now moot. Most of these questions are answered by [this one](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/18820/2880).